# Calculate the norm of this operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

$C[0,1]=\{ f : [0,1]\to [0,1], f$ continuous$\}$

$||f||_\infty=\max_{t\in [0,1]} |f(t)|$

$T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$
defined by 
$$(Tf)(t)=\int_0^1e^{s+t}f(s)ds$$

Find $||T||$

The usual way to do this kind of exercises (at least what I have seen until now) is

1. We have $||T||=\inf\{M : ||T(f)||\leq M ||f||\}$
2. We have $||T||=\sup_{||f||\leq 1}\{||T(f)||\}$

so by one side we have  to find a $M$ (using 1.) then $||T||\leq M$ and by the other side we have to use 2, finding a $||f_0||\leq 1$ with $||T(f_0)||\geq M$. Then we have $||T||=M$.

I have done this
Usually the easy part is the part 1. Because to use part 2. you have to choose a appropriated $ f $.

1. $$||Tf||_\infty:=\max_{t\in[a,b]}|\int_0^1 e^{s+t}f(s)ds|\leq\max_{t\in[a,b]}\int_0^1 e^{s+t}|f(s)|ds\leq [\max_{t\in[a,b]}\int_0^1e^{s+t}ds]||f||_\infty$$

so $M$ should be $\max_{t\in[a,b]}\int_0^1e^{s+t}ds$. 
but I can not find a $f_0$ to use the point 2.
Some Help Please!

Comment: What is the norm you're using for $C[0,1]$?

Comment: Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Comment: Edited, I am a new user, I am not English speaker I did not read the rules and recommendations of this site.  Sorry!

Comment: Hint: $e^{s+t} = e^t\cdot e^s$. The operator $T$ is a linear form in disguise.

Comment: Please check what I answered below is correct. Thank you for the the comment in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing what I said above. And with the help of Daniel Fischer.

$$M=\max_{t\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 e^{s+t} ds=\max_{t\in[0,1]}e^t\int_0^1 e^s ds=e(e-1)$$

And if we take $f_0=f(t)=1\quad \forall t\in [0,1]$ then $f\in C[0,1]$ and $||f||_\infty=1$.

$$||Tf_0||=\max_{t\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 e^{s+t} ds=\max_{t\in[0,1]}e^t\int_0^1 e^s ds=e(e-1)=M$$

and this shows $||T||\geq e(e-1)$, with the previous $||T||\leq e(e-1)$ we have $||T||=M$

Comment: Yep, that's right.